# Can read concern "Snapshot" solve my problem?

Tags: java, mongodb, crud

I'm trying to do a huge query that retrieves  every documents in multiple collections in a database.
The problem is that I want to make sure that the documents are coherent since some of them are linked together and i want to make sure no documents are modified during my find.

While reading the mongo documentation, I came across the read concern Snapshot but I dont really understand if it will solve my problem and since it's hard to actually try it out, I wanted to ask you guys for some help.
I've already tried the transactions and they do not seem to work well for me :/

Thanks for your time !
Have a nice day